# SOAP, and BasicHttpBinding Data Integrity

Tags: wcf, soap, basichttpbinding

I am drafting a design for a web service that will communicate with another web service to conduct a "search". In my response DTO, I have an array of a complex type (wrapped inside of another compex type) indicating the results. B may return to A zero, one, or many items in this array. It is my intention that if the search was fruitless, the array would simply be empty. My colleagues insist that Web Service B should always return one item in the array, and - if the search was fruitless - the first object would have a sentinel property value indicating no results were found. The idea is that B needs to explicitly tell A there were no search results instead of it being self-evident from the state of the array. They envision a chance that B intended to send a set of objects and somehow managed to only send some or zero items in its response to A, and that A can explicitly understand if there was a mistake or a snafu with this sentinel value.

My gut tells me that B shouldn't have to "explicitly" tell A there were zero results, that the effort is redundant and unnecessary due to our technology stack (WCF, SOAP, httpBasicBinding). I tried googling, but could not find any concrete documentation on how this tech stack can deal with technical mishaps between web services.

Comment: It certainly wouldn't hurt to have B explicitly tell A that nothing was found.  A and B are disconnected, so there is **always** the possibility that something can go awry.  Unless you control A, B **and** everything in between, you cannot guarantee that nothing will happen.

Comment: @Tim: I dont understand how a sentinel value is any more useful than the object's state itself. The sentinel value can also be corrupted. What if the array is correct and the sentinel value is not? I do know that malformed SOAP is the problem, WCF wont even execute A's operation so that's certainly not an issue.